# JSON Parsing GET method, trying to display values in Spinner

Tags: android, json, android-volley, spinner

I am trying to display values in Spinner by using JSON parsing, but it's not taking the centerID and giving me error as " centerID not found". And, nothing is displaying in Spinner View.

// This is my API file

```
BASE_URL : http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/
API URL : BASE_URL/users/getdoctorslist/$center_id
METHOD : GET
PARAMETER TO PASS:
                center_id=4
INPUT:
        BASE_URL/users/getdoctorslist/4
OUTPUT:
          {
    "status": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "doctor_id": "1",
            "first_name": "Dr. Sagar",
            "last_name": "Patil"
        },
        {
            "doctor_id": "2",
            "first_name": "Dr. Ashwini",
            "last_name": "D"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Get Doctors list successfully!"
}

Errors:
1)
       {
           "status": false,
        "message": "Center id should not empty!"
        }
2)
       {
           "status": false,
        "message": "There is no Center data found!"
}
```

This is the config file where I am doing Connection

```
public class Config {

  //JSON URL
  public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/users/getdoctorslist/{center_id}";

  //Tags used in the JSON String
  public static final String TAG_DOC_ID = "doctor_id";
  public static final String TAG_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
  public static final String TAG_LAST_NAME = "last_name";

  //JSON array name
  public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

This is my fragment where I am trying to fetch the values in Spinner using Volley library

```
private ArrayList<String> docList;

//JSON Array
private JSONArray result;
private Spinner doctorLists;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_patient, container, false);

    doctorLists = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.doctors_list);
    //Initializing the ArrayList
    docList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //This method will fetch the data from the URL
    getData();
    return view;  
} // closing onCreateView()

private void getData(){
  //Creating a string request
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,Config.DATA_URL,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      JSONObject j = null;
      try {
        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
        j = new JSONObject(response);

        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
        getDoctors(result);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  },
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
  @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
  });

  //Creating a request queue
  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
  //Adding request to the queue
  requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getDoctors(JSONArray j){
  //Traversing through all the items in the json array
  for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
    try {
      //Getting json object
      JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

      //Adding the name of the student to array list
      docList.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_FIRST_NAME));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
  doctorLists.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, docList));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing request method

use this
your Api need to pass center_id as parameter when its called

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,Config.DATA_URL,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
JSONObject j = null;
try {
//Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
j = new JSONObject(response);

//Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

//Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
getDoctors(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

}
}){ @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("center_id", "4");
            return params;
        };

//Creating a request queue
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
//Adding request to the queue
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

if still it is not work let me know

Comment: i have made the changes,but still nothing is displaying in Spinner

Comment: i have edited my answer,try it.You are not passing "center_id" parameter when api called.

Comment: Or you can also try " Config.DATA_URL+YOUR CENTER_ID" in StringRequest

Comment: @Override  // here im getting error
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { // at throws im getting one more error
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("center_id", "4");
            return params;
        };

Comment: have you checked your api url in postman? if you checked in postman then in postman you are getting correct respons?

Comment: because i have checked your api url in postman.and it is not showing response

Comment: because i am hitting the local server that's why you are not getting the response

Comment: ok. remober  getHeaders()  and add this "Config.DATA_URL+YOUR CENTER_ID" in StringRequest

Comment: I have removed getHeaders() and it's working for me when I am taking like this .Config.DATA_URL+4 and it's working fine, But now I have saved center_id in sharedPreference and I am getting the value like this Config.DATA_URL+sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class).getResult().getCenterId() . but after doing this it's not showing any value in spinner

Comment: first try this checking whether you are getting value from sharedPreference"String xyz=sharePreferenceManager.getUserLoginData(LoginModel.class).getResult().getCenterId() 
Log.d("===","xyz::  "+xyz);"

If you get value from sharedPrefrence then pass xyz with url

Comment: Hello, actually i am getting one more problem in spinner. I am not getting the value of the selected item of the spinner, which i need to pass to the Api call. Can you help me in this please..

Comment: add setOnItemSelectedListener method of sppiner and add this line "String  selectedText=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();" in onItemSelected.Now, pass selectedText in api

Comment: done with the same thing, still getting the selected name

Comment: @kevinKurien  I don't have that much reputation

Comment: @ShrutiB hi, could you please help at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498385/how-to-pass-parameters-in-webview?

Answer (score 0):

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,...
```

You're not setting the `center_id` argument in your request

Answer (score 0):

Already you have information about your API.

```
API URL : BASE_URL/users/getdoctorslist/$center_id
METHOD : GET
PARAMETER TO PASS:
                center_id=4
INPUT:
        BASE_URL/users/getdoctorslist/4
```

Your API need a value `$center_id` but you didn't pass the value. You requested url is

```
"http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/users/getdoctorslist/{center_id}"
```

Please send a value of center_id.

Try this

```
final String url = "http://192.168.1.80/aoplnew/api/users/getdoctorslist/4";

    // prepare the Request
    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
                    try {
                      //Parsing the fetched JSON String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getDoctors(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", response);
                }
            }
    );

    // add it to the RequestQueue   
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
```

//Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

Comment: @Override // here im getting error                                                                
 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { // at throws im getting one more error                                                                                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); params.put("Content-Type", "application/json"); params.put("center_id", "4"); return params; };

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at English.

I recommend use GSON for convert json string to object:
https://github.com/google/gson

and recommend use retrofit for connect to service:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/